# Problema con listas que incluyen funciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones

tengo el siguiente problema:

En un archivo, yo definí las siguientes funciones:

```
def sala1():
    print ("sala1")

def sala2():
    print ("sala2")

def sala3():
    print ("sala3")
```

Además de eso, la siguiente lista que se conforma por dichas funciones

```
mi_sala = [sala1(),sala2(),sala3()]
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto el código para probar que todo vaya bien, en consola, esas funciones se ejecutan por el simple hecho de encontrarse dentro de la lista, les muestro lo que se ve en consola:

```
sala1
sala2
sala3
```

¿Me podrían sugerir una solución para que esto no pase?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se ejecutan porque en el literal de lista las ejecutas explícitamente:

```
mi_sala = [sala1(), sala2(), sala3()]
                ^^       ^^       ^^
                ^^       ^^       ^^
```

Te muestra lo que te muestra en consola porque cada función tiene un `print`. Cuando el intérprete genera la lista ejecuta cada función porque así lo indicas y la lista tendrá referencias a los objetos  retornados por  cada función, que como no retornas nada explícitamente en ninguna de ellas será una lista de `None` (valor por defecto de retorno de todo método o función):

> ```
> >>> mi_sala
> [None, None, None]
> ```

Si quieres que la lista almacene funciones, estrictamente hablando, referencias a objetos `function`, no debes usar el paréntesis de llamada:

```
mi_sala = [sala1, sala2, sala3]
```

> ```
> >>> mi_sala
> [<function sala1 at 0x7f793191f700>, <function sala2 at 0x7f795236f704>, <function sala3 at 0x7f593191f732>]
> ```

Ahora puedes usar tu lista como harías con cualquier lista, solo que cada item es ahora una referencia a una función y por tanto puedes llamarlo cuando quieras ejecutarla:

> ```
> >>> mi_sala[0]()
> sala1
>
> >>> sala2_fun = mi_sala[1]
> >>> type(sala2_fun)
> <class 'function'>
> >>> sala2_fun()
> sala2
>
> >>> for fun in mi_sala:
>         fun()
> sala1
> sala2
> sala3
> ```

Comúnmente se dice las funciones son "objetos de primera clase" o "funciones de primera clase" cuando pueden pasarse como argumentos a otras funciones, retornarse por otras funciones, ser contenidas en estructuras contenedoras o asociarse a variables. En Python realmente no tienen nada de especial, son objetos en memoria como cualquier otra cosa que exista con la peculiaridad de ser callables y algunas optimizaciones que hace el intéprete. Como cualquier objeto por tanto son susceptible de que una variable pueda asociarse a una referencia a la función, que cualquier contenedor (lista, diccionario, conjunto, tupla, etc) pueda contener referencias a ellas y que otra función pueda tomarla como argumento o retornarla.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó demasiado, el problema es que ahora me surge una duda:

Si tomo un elemento de la lista utilizando un random, y guardo ese resultado en una variable, ¿como debería de hacer para utilizar el valor de esa variable y que al yo ejecutar un `print()` me muestre cual fué el resultado de esa elección random? Ej: Si el random, escogió la sala2 y lo guardó en la variable `sala_actual` ¿que hago para que yo al colocar `print (sala_actual)` NO me arroje: <function sala2 at 0x00000192A2D93E18>?

Me serías de mucha ayuda.

De igual manera gracias.

Comment: Debes ejecutar lo que ¿`random.choice`? te retorne, que será una referencia a la fucnión por ejemplo: `sala_actual = random.choice(mi_sala)()`. Pero las funciones no deben imprimir si las vas a usar así, deben retornar lo que quieras que tu variable contenga luego, es decir, en vez de `print("sala1")` en la función debes hacer  `return 'sala1'`, lo mismo para las otras.